# How to Search for a String that is existing in Different web pages using crawler4j

Tags: java, crawler4j

I am using Crawler4j it is returning output as  Processed Pages: 10
   Total Links found: 369
   Total Text Size: 20077
up to this it is working fine but i want to search a string which is existing in this pages how can i achieve this could you please help me

Answer (score 0):

to search string you must download page source code and then using string comparision to find what you want.